# Excel VBA - Can't refer to objects/can't drop the info into sheet

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have some problems with an interface I'm making. I'm new to this and after a lot of search, I finally gave up and came here to ask.

First of all I made my code do this:

- Open a userform from a button on a sheet.
- After the userform is open, it has some default fields (some textboxes, a label and a commandbutton).
- Then you have a commandbutton that creates a new round of fields and assign them a class to execute some simple code (numerical restriction for some textboxes and create a new textbox with content for the button).

My problem is the following :

- I tried to assign `ControlSource` to the fields but Excel doesnt allow me to, and the only time it allowed me to, the fields didn't update the cell nor the cell updated the field.
- I also tried to load the value from the newly created field directly into the sheet but I don't know how to call the object and get its properties.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
Option Explicit
Dim cargarconcepto() As New Clase3
Private Sub CommandButton19_Click()
Dim txtCtl As Control
Dim concepto As Object
    Dim i As Long

    i = labelcounter




controlextra = controlextra + 1
Dim Label As Object
Dim lblctr As Long
Dim nmctr As Long
Dim t1 As Object
Dim t2 As Control
Dim t3 As Control
Dim t4 As Control
Dim t5 As Object
Dim t6 As Object
Dim cargaconcepto As Control


UserForm1.Frame21.ScrollHeight = 80 + (25 * controlextra) - 25
UserForm1.Frame21.ScrollTop = UserForm1.Frame21.ScrollHeight
nmctr = labelcounter + 1



For lblctr = labelcounter To controlextra
    Set Label = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Labelt" & labelcounter, True)
    With Label
        .Caption = "0005 - "
        .Left = 3
        .Height = 12
        .Width = 24
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
    End With
        Set t1 = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "t" & labelcounter + 1 & "1", True)
    With t1
        .value = Workbooks("A Facturar Proyecto tarjetas.xlsm").Sheets("Data").Range("as1").value
        .Left = 31
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        .Enabled = False
        .Height = 15.75
        .Width = 54
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
    End With
    Set t2 = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "t" & labelcounter + 1 & "2", False)
    With t2
        .value = ""
        .Left = 97
        .Height = 15.75
        .Width = 90
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
        .Visible = True
    End With
     Set t3 = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "t" & labelcounter + 1 & "3", False)
    With t3
        .value = ""
        .Left = 199
        .Height = 15.75
        .Width = 90
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Set t4 = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "t" & labelcounter + 1 & "4", False)
    With t4
        .value = ""
        .Left = 307
        .Height = 15.75
        .Width = 90
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Set t5 = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "t" & labelcounter + 1 & "5", True)
    With t5
        .value = ""
        .Left = 415
        .Height = 15.75
        .Width = 90
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
    End With
    Set t6 = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "t" & labelcounter + 1 & "6", True)
    With t6
        .value = ""
        .Left = 517
        .Height = 15.75
        .Width = 90
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
    End With
     Set concepto = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "concepto" & labelcounter + 1, False)
    With concepto
        .value = ""
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
        .Left = 619
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 210
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
        .Enabled = False
        .value = Workbooks("A Facturar Proyecto tarjetas").Sheets("Data").Range("Ac45")
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Set cargaconcepto = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("forms.commandbutton.1", "Cargar Concepto" & labelcounter + 1, False)
    With cargaconcepto
        .Caption = "Cargar Concepto"
        .Left = 834
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 90
        .Top = 25 + (25 * labelcounter)
        .Tag = labelcounter + 1
        .Visible = True
    End With



    ReDim Preserve num(1 To i)
    Set num(i).txtCtrl = t2
    ReDim Preserve num2(1 To i)
    Set num2(i).txtCtrl = t3
    ReDim Preserve num3(1 To i)
    Set num3(i).txtCtrl = t4
    ReDim Preserve cargarconcepto(1 To i)
    Set cargarconcepto(i).cargar = cargaconcepto

    Set cargaconcepto = Nothing
    Set t3 = Nothing
    Set t4 = Nothing
    Set t2 = Nothing


    labelcounter = labelcounter + 1


Next

End Sub
```

And then here is the class:

```
    Option Explicit
    Public WithEvents cargar As MSForms.CommandButton
    Private Sub cargar_Click()
    Dim concepto As Control


    Set concepto = UserForm1.Frame21.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "concepto" & labelcounter + 1, True)
        With concepto
            .value = ""
            .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
            .Left = 619
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 210
            .Top = (25 * b)
            .Enabled = False
            .value = Workbooks("A Facturar Proyecto tarjetas").Sheets("Data").Range("Ac45")
        End With
    End Sub
```

I tried to use something like `UserForm1.Frame21.concepto & cargar.Tag` to get the name of the newly created field and therefore replace its value for a new one AND to load that value into the sheet.
But I just cant find a way to do it. Now I have an almost complete interface for data entry but I cant drop the data into the spreadsheet.

Please I need help!